# Question on weak-star convergence in $L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$

Tags: weak-convergence

Could you please tell me what does it mean
$u_n \rightarrow u$ weak-star in $L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ ?

Comment: $L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ should be the dual space of something. There is a natural candiate. // You didn't say what $\Omega$ is. Presumably an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Please explain a bit more where you got lost, in order to be able to help.

Comment: yes, $\Omega$ is domain in $R^n$

Comment: $L^{\infty}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ is dual space to $L^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$

Answer (score 4):

*General definition*. If $X$ is a normed space with dual $X^*$, we say that a sequence $u_n$ in $X^*$ converges to $u$ in weak* topology if for every $v\in X$ we have $\langle u_n, v\rangle\to \langle u, v\rangle$. So, the question reduces to identifying $X$ and $X^*$, and the pairing  of $X^*$ on $X$.

Given that $X=L^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ and $X^*=L^{\infty}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$,   the presumed pairing is 
$$\langle u,v\rangle=\int_0^T \int_\Omega u(x,t)\,v(x,t)\,dx  \,dt$$
Or with a conjugate $\overline{v(x,t)}$ if we are dealing with complex spaces.

Thus: for every $v\in L^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$
$$\int_0^T \int_\Omega u_n(x,t)\,v(x,t)\,dx \,dt\to \int_0^T \int_\Omega u(x,t)\,v(x,t)\,dx \,dt$$